# django user not authenticating

Tags: python, django-views

authenticate is not working , the user=authenticate(username=username,password=password) is returning None.
the user is none here and thus nothing is working

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "form2" in request.POST:
            form = Userform(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user=form.save()
                print(user.password)
                login(request,user)
                return redirect("main:dashboard")
            else:
                messages.error(request,'invalid entry')
                return redirect("main:homepage")

        elif "form1" in request.POST:
            username=request.POST["email1"]
            password=request.POST["password1"]
            print(username)
            print(password)

            user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)

            print(user)
            if user is not None:
                print("hello")
                login(request,user)

                return redirect("main:dashboard")
            else:
                messages.error(request,'user doesnot exist')
                return redirect("main:homepage")
    form = Userform
    return render(request,
                    "index.html",{"form":form}
                       )
```

Comment: assuming this is the [authenticate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) function from `django.contrib.auth`, that can only mean your user doesn't exist or you have the wrong password. Without knowing what's in your database and what information is being entered, I don't see how anyone can offer any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like missing `request` in `authenticate()`. Try adding that and see.

```
user=authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
```

Example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
<<import LoginForm/UserForm>>

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(request,
                                username=cd['username'],
                                password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated Successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled Account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/auth/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: it worked with the authentication form but is not working with the form i created in html .... i tried adding request but the problem remained.... thanks anyways.